# rake test:prepare fails with Rails 4.0.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rspec, rake

I was testing my app (with rspec) when I noticed `rake test:prepare` throws an odd `FATAL: database "postgres" does not exist` error. Stranger still, my tests run just fine regardless.

However, whenever I use `rake test:prepare --trace` (after using `rake db:migrate`) I get this error and receive the same error when attempting `rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test` and also `rake db:drop RAILS_ENV=test` as well. Any idea what I may be overlooking?

Here is the error in question:

```
** Invoke test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment
** Invoke db:load_config
** Execute db:test:purge
rake aborted!
```

`PG::Error: FATAL: database "postgres" does not exist`

```
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:855:in `initialize'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:855:in `new'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:855:in `connect'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:556:in `initialize'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in checkout'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `connection'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:30:in `drop'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:43:in `purge'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `purge'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:365:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:371:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/Wilhelm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails_4_0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

`Tasks: TOP => db:test:load => db:test:purge`

Here is what my test environment looks like (according to my gemfile):

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.8'
gem 'pg', '0.15.1'

group :development, :test do
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
    gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
    gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end
```

## Edit

Here is what my `database.yml` file looks like :

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  endoding: unicode
  database: myapp_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  hostname: localhost

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  endoding: unicode
  database: myapp_test
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  hostname: localhost

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: myapp_production
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Comment: What's the configuration in `database.yml`?

Comment: @Sam I've updated my entry to include the contents of my database.yml file

Comment: Did you try creating a database called 'postgres'?

Comment: @AFaderDarkly I received a similar `FATAL: database "postgres" does not exist error` when attempting `rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test`

Comment: I think you need to step outside rails here. It appears that Rails is depending on there being a database **called** postgres on your Postgres server. You will need some kind of Postgres client (the official one will do, or the command line) with which you can create databases on your Postgres server.

Comment: When I say 'the command line' I mean using the Postgres command-line client, rather than doing it through Rails. http://www.commandprompt.com/ppbook/c12119

Comment: @AFaderDarkly I'm familiar [rails dbconsole](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-dbconsole) and am comfortable with the command line console. Unfortunately you're providing me with very little insight. Were you able to replicate the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58114/discussion-between-a-fader-darkly-and-wilhelm).

Answer (score -1):

Try using a Postgres client(pgAdmin3 for example, or psql on the command line) to attempt to create a database named 'postgres' on your server. Don't try using Rails rake tasks to do this - they will probably fail for the same reason.

Using psql you could try:

```
CREATE DATABASE postgres;
```

or use pgAdmin3 (free with Postgres) if you prefer a GUI.

You will need to be logged in as a user with the appropriate privileges for creating databases.

As I understand it, this database is created automatically by newer versions of Postgres. It needs no tables. Your instance of Postgres may not have it or it may have been deleted or renamed, but the database adapter used by Rails needs it to be there for some reason.

Comment: If you're going to down-vote me, let me know why. If the proposed solution failed to work, let me know how it failed so I can attempt to help further.

Comment: Apologies. The comment was aimed at whoever did the down-voting, but admittedly could have been worded better.